# Textbooks with non-trivial $2D$ Cartesian curve sketching exercises

Tags: calculus, reference-request, curves

I'm looking for textbooks that have a decent amount of curve sketching exercises. I have been disappointed with how much this topic has been skipped over lightly by most textbooks, often summarised in a page. That said, I've had most luck in calculus textbooks. I am aware of a book called "A treatise on curve sketching", but I am more interested in newer textbooks that make use of calculus, if possible.

Comment: An amazing reference not on curve sketching but on curves: https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/courbes2d.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The reference I have is *[Skills in Mathematics-Play with Graphs](https://www.amazon.in/Skills-Mathematics-Play-Graphs-Advanced/dp/9313191946/ref=pd_lpo_14_t_0/260-7646918-5528613?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=9313191946&pd_rd_r=ca9fd699-e4b1-48ab-9ae8-5131d202412b&pd_rd_w=n4Gff&pd_rd_wg=MDcLE&pf_rd_p=5a903e39-3cff-40f0-9a69-33552e242181&pf_rd_r=ZA0H0951HFA3A5AVFXX6&psc=1&refRID=ZA0H0951HFA3A5AVFXX6)* by Amit M.Agarwal. Although this textbook caters to a specific examination(the IIT-JEE, an engineering entrance exam), it thoroughly covers sketching of elementary curves and finding solutions of equations using these curves. Availability of this textbook could be a problem outside of India, but if it's available, I consider it to be an excellent treatise.